# How do the bonus perks from the Advanced Warfare Center work?

Tags: xcom-2

One of the first buildings available to you is the Advanced Warfare Center (AWC).

Once you have this building, your soldiers can randomly be granted bonus perks when they level up. Obviously, perks are pretty powerful, so I'd like to acquire as many as possible.

How many bonus perks can you receive? What determines what bonus perk you get? And are there any limitations on which perks you can actually receive?

Comment: So this is the first XCOM 2 question around here! The king is dead, long live the king!

Comment: Guessing related to this? http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/254295/what-hidden-abilities-are-available

Comment: @RobertWertz Looks like a duplicate of this one.

Comment: How can it be a duplicate if there are no answers?  Bonus perks =/= hidden abilities

Comment: @skully I think both are asking the same question from different sides. The correct answer will address both questions. 

If you read the screenshot in the other question it specifically says "Thanks to the efforts of the Advanced Warfare Center, this solder has learned a combat ability outside of their area of specialization."

Comment: @skully Bonus perks *are* the same as hidden abilities, though

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Found a post on the XCOM subreddit from one of the Long War devs, Amineri:

> I should clarify how this works.
>
> The AWC doesn't give a random chance to gain an ability on each
>   level-up.
>
> What happens is that each soldier gets a single AWC ability rolled for
>   either when the AWC is built (for existing soldiers) or when the
>   soldier is obtained (AWC already built).
>
> The AWC ability is randomly pulled from "cross class abilities" -- not
>   a list, but configured with a boolean in each ability.
>
> The AWC is stored along with the level at which it will unlock. When
>   the soldier reaches that level (or returning from first mission if
>   already there), then the ability will be unlocked.
>
> Source: I looked at the code, and the LW Officer mod stores the
>   officer abilities in the same AWCAbilities array.

So, from this, it seems the answers are, 1, a random selection from "allowed cross class abilities", and yes, but see [this question](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/254295/what-hidden-abilities-are-available).

Comment: It should be noted that when units roll for their AWC upgrades, if they're already past the level that they rolled, they lose the upgrade forever. There is a mod that fixes this bug [here](http://steamcommunity.com/sharedfiles/filedetails/?id=620586407).

Comment: Without mod, soldier may undergo retraining to get that ability.