# What determines the psi stat in Xcom 2?

Tags: xcom-2

I fully trained four psi operatives and each one has a different psi stat. The lowest is 87 and highest is 99.

What determines my psi stat ?

Would learning higher level abilities that take longer than five days to train add more psi per lvlup?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You start with 50 when the Psi Operative gets his first ability and get a random amount (min 4, max 12) every time he is promoted. The Psi Operative is promoted every time he learns a new ability, until he reaches the maximum level (level 7, Magus). The unmodified stat is capped at 100, which means a Magus has 74-100 Psi stat, but the expected value is much closer to 100 than 74.

The stat gains for every promotion are defined in one of the .ini files (DefaultClassData.ini). Will grows the same way as Psi Offense (+4-12 per promotion with 100 cap) but you can also get extra will when you bring a shaken soldier for a mission.

Comment: How do you know this? Any idea what determines the will stat?

Comment: The stat gains for every promotion are defined in one of the .ini files (DefaultClassData.ini). Will grows the same way as Psi Offense (+4-12 per promotion with 100 cap) but you can also get extra will when you bring a shaken soldier for a mission.

Comment: @SkyHiRider, keep in mind: will is *entirely separate* from psi attack.  This makes the Focus PCS even less useful than it might have been.

Comment: @Kikanaide: I once replaced superior agility PCS on my magus with superior focus, hoping it'll give me 100% chance to dominate gatekeepers. Big mistake!